# How to delete entire site directory if login attempts reach maximum

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a very confidential site where only a few people have access to logging in. How do I check if a user has attempted to login in three times and if they have, the entire directory is deleted from my server. Is this difficult to do?

Here is my login page:

```
<?php
require_once('scripts/user_authentication.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inder' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Access login</title>
<link href="../styles/users.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
span {font-family: 'Inder', sans-serif; color: #369; font-style: italic;}

#login {width: 400px; margin: 60px auto 0 auto; padding: 20px; text-align: center; 
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
}

#login p {text-align: left;}

form {padding: 0; margin: 0; }
input {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

h1 { margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 0;}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="login">
<h1><span>p*******</span> Partners Only</h1>
<div id="inner">
<?php if ($failed) { ?>
<p class="warning">Login failed. Try Again. Please contact ******* ***** if you do not know your access information. After multiple attempts this site will self destruct. Thank you for your cooperation.</p>
<?php } ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="Sign in" />
  </p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is user_authentication:

```
<?php
$failed = FALSE;
if ($_POST) {
  if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $failed = TRUE;
  } else {
    require_once('library.php');
    // check the user's credentials
    try {
      $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
      $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbRead, 'users', 'first_name', 'family_name', 'password' 'sha1(?)');
      $adapter->setIdentity($_POST['username']);
      $adapter->setCredential($_POST['password']);
      $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
      if ($result->isValid()) {
        $storage = $auth->getStorage();
        $storage->write($adapter->getResultRowObject(array(
          'username', 'first_name', 'family_name')));
        header('Location: members_only.php');
        exit;
      } else {
        $failed = TRUE;
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  require_once('library.php');
  try {
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->clearIdentity();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to delete the directory? What if the user has forgotten the password or what if someone else is trying to use the username to access the page?

Comment: This is a very dangerous approach. Makes it easy for an attacker to.. well.. delete stuff from your server, making it inaccessible to your real users.

Comment: If you post the URL I'm sure someone will test it for you ;)

Comment: This is **stupid** - you might want to consider different approaches such as blocking by IP, or blocking by attempted username. Why would you delete it off your server!!!??

Comment: Why Dr. Strangelove - you've invented your very own Doomsday Machine :)  http://www.wired.com/politics/security/magazine/17-10/mf_deadhand?currentPage=all

Comment: This must be a government project.

Comment: This is a governmental project that requires everything to be completely deleted. It is just informational content that can easily be replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach (deleting files for the user) is **really bad practice**, but if you absolutely need to do it, here is one way...

Create a database table (or entries in an existing table) to store the username and number of attempts. Before authenticating, check the attempts are below a set amount. In the authentication part, if the password is wrong, increment the "attempts" column. Whenever the user successfully logs in, set attempts to zero again. If they exceed the number of attempts, delete the files or take whatever security measures you need to.

Now, to make this design better, I would suggest not to actually delete the data on the server. Instead, I would recommend that after X number of failed attempts, increased security measures are applied to people attempting to log in for that username, such as;

- require the user to solve a captcha so you know they aren't a bot trying multiple passwords
- store "security questions" for each user (e.g. "What is your birthday"), and require them to answer those
- lock the account out and have a secure procedure for the real user to gain access again

Answer (score 1):

As people mentioned in the comments it is very dangerous doing that.

However, if you still believe that the information is of that importance and the link to the login page is very secret and you have backups somewhere else, this code should do it:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Add this only if you don't have it in some other header files

// Checking if the session variable exists and initiating it if it does not.
if (!isset($_SESSION['failed'])) {
    $_SESSION['failed'] = 0;
}

$failed = FALSE;
if ($_POST) {
  if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $failed = TRUE;
  } else {
    require_once('library.php');
    // check the user's credentials
    try {
      $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
      $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbRead, 'users', 'first_name', 'family_name', 'password' 'sha1(?)');
      $adapter->setIdentity($_POST['username']);
      $adapter->setCredential($_POST['password']);
      $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
      if ($result->isValid()) {

        // Setting the counter to 0 in case of successful login.
        $_SESSION['failed'] = 0;

        $storage = $auth->getStorage();
        $storage->write($adapter->getResultRowObject(array(
          'username', 'first_name', 'family_name')));
        header('Location: members_only.php');
        exit;
      } else {
        $failed = TRUE;

        // Increment the failed logins counter at each failed login.
        $_SESSION['failed']++;

        // In case of 3 or more failed attempts
        if ($_SESSION['failed'] > 3) {

            // Remove some directory
            rmdir("/path/to/the/dir");
            $_SESSION['failed'] = 0;
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  require_once('library.php');
  try {
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->clearIdentity();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Despite the fact that all idea is very bad, I would add to above code instructions to initiate session variable if it does not exist and set session counter to 0 when user is authenticated successfully :)

Comment: Thanks sir minor refactoring was made =)

Comment: does this code go inside the login page? Also this will not affect any db information right?

Comment: This is a change to the `user_authentication` file that you provided. This does not affect the database.

Comment: now i'm getting this error when I put in the wrong credentials, "session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()"